# Has anyone been able to overcome "unable to find device" error in the AWS Device Farm for iOS?

Tags: ios, automated-tests, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, aws-device-farm

I'm trying to run some UI automation tests for iOS in the AWS Device Farm. However, I keep on getting the following error:

[error: Unable to find device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwW3N.png)

The company I work for doesn't have the free access to their support, so it makes a little harder to reach out Amazon themselves to seek an answer.

I have basically followed all of the following steps on how to set it all up from this link: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/how-to-run-your-iphone-test-on-aws-device-farm-98f18086811e 
(I'm using XCTest in the device farm). If anyone have managed to overcome the same or similar issue, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Correction: I'm using XCTest UI and not XCTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're continuously getting that error I would think something is wrong with the test package.  Try running a fuzz test using the same devices and same IPA file.  If those execute then it's definitely something wrong with the test package.

Hope that helps.

James.

Also AWS dev support is the greater of $29 or 3% of bill per month. It might just take longer to get a response with that plan than others.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/developer-support/

Comment: To clarify, AWS Developer Support is the "greater of $29 or 3% of bill" per month.

Comment: modified my answer. Thanks Rafael Fonseca

Comment: Thanks for your help @jmp. The fuzz tests passed, so I'm assuming the issue is to do with the testing package. I'll try another sample app first, in order to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a post in the AWS-deviceFarm forum and giving your 
account ID and run URL
so they will take a look at your test, and which specific device(s) were you used.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193&start=0